# Overlapping box-shadow with float divs

Tags: css, overlapping

### Code

http://jsfiddle.net/LtZAv/

### What is expected

- top shadow of second `.child .comment-box` is displayed and overlapping the first `.child .comment-box`

### What browser renders

- box shadow of second `.child .comment-box` in the region of `div.content` with `float:right` is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the display of the li.child so that the contents of div.content do not escape it.

Add this CSS :

```
li.child { display: inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwood/LtZAv/2/

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the position of **comment-box**  div to **relative**

like

```
.comment-box { position: relative; }
```

so shadow will overlap the first div.

Comment: Absolutely CORRECT. Some people also adds a higher z-index, which does not seems to be required. (it works with the relative positioning alone)